# How to fill a DataGridViewComboBoxColumn?

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, datagridviewcomboboxcell, datagridviewcomboboxcolumn

Sorry if this is something that should be obvious, but this is my first project using VB.NET, and some things are still beyond me.

I'm trying to setup a combobox inside a DataGridView but I keep getting

> System.ArgumentException: DatagridviewComboBoxCell value not valid

I've been googling this for 2 hours now and to me it seems I'm setting up thing correctly, but probably something is amiss.

```
Dim imageCol As DataGridViewImageColumn
Dim checkCol As DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn
Dim col As DataGridViewColumn
Dim comboCol As DataGridViewComboBoxColumn
Dim ds As DataSet
Dim som As New SomStructure
Dim somministrazioni() As SomStructure = {}

With dgvListaAttivita
    .Columns.Clear()
    .AutoGenerateColumns = False
    .ReadOnly = False
    .EditMode = DataGridViewEditMode.EditOnEnter
    .CausesValidation = False

    somministrazioni.Clear
    ds = getSomministrazioni(codevalue, Today())
    If ds IsNot Nothing Then
        For Each row As DataRow In ds.Tables(0).Rows
            som.idOspite = row(0)
            som.nomeOspite = row(1)
            som.descrizioneSomministrazione = row(2)
            som.idOperatore = row(3)
            som.nomeOperatore = row(4)
            som.preparata = False
            somministrazioni.Add(som)
        Next
    End If

    .DataSource = somministrazioni

    imageCol = New DataGridViewImageColumn
    imageCol.Width = 25
    imageCol.ImageLayout = DataGridViewImageCellLayout.Normal
    imageCol.Description = "delete"
    imageCol.Image = My.Resources.note
    .Columns.Add(imageCol)


    col = New DataGridViewColumn
    col.DataPropertyName = "descrizioneSomministrazione"
    col.HeaderText = "Somministrazione"
    col.ValueType = GetType(String)
    col.CellTemplate = New DataGridViewTextBoxCell
    col.AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.Fill
    col.ReadOnly = True
    .Columns.Add(col)


    comboCol = New DataGridViewComboBoxColumn
    Dim dt As DataTable = dsOperatori.Tables(0)
    comboCol.DataSource = dt
    comboCol.DisplayMember = "display"
    comboCol.ValueMember = "idoperatore"
    comboCol.DataPropertyName = "idOperatore"
    comboCol.HeaderText = "Operatore"
    comboCol.ValueType = GetType(Integer)
    comboCol.CellTemplate = New DataGridViewComboBoxCell
    comboCol.Width = 150
    .Columns.Add(comboCol)


    checkCol = New DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn
    checkCol.DataPropertyName = "preparata"
    checkCol.HeaderText = "P."
    checkCol.ValueType = GetType(Boolean)
    checkCol.CellTemplate = New DataGridViewCheckBoxCell
    checkCol.Width = 20
    .Columns.Add(checkCol)

End With
```

As I understand it it should be like this:

```
comboCol.DataSource = dt
comboCol.DisplayMember = "display"
comboCol.ValueMember = "idoperatore"
```

specifies the datasource and key/display values of the comboboxes in the column

```
comboCol.DataPropertyName = "idOperatore"
```

Is the name of the column linked to both the DataSource of the DataGridView and the ValueMember of the ComboBox, and that should display different selections on different rows.

If I remove the DataPropertyName from the code I don't get the error anymore, but I also get empty comboboxes.

Comment: Try commenting out this line `comboCol.CellTemplate = New DataGridViewComboBoxCell`

Comment: That was it, thanks. Though I have to ask, because I find it bizarre, how come the other columns need it while the combobox type does not?

Comment: Not sure on the "why".  I just took your code and commented out that line.  I rarely ever have to set that property whenever I have to use the DataGridView myself, so that made me test it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try commenting out the template line:

```
comboCol = New DataGridViewComboBoxColumn
Dim dt As DataTable = dsOperatori.Tables(0)
comboCol.DataSource = dt
comboCol.DisplayMember = "display"
comboCol.ValueMember = "idoperatore"
comboCol.DataPropertyName = "idOperatore"
comboCol.HeaderText = "Operatore"
comboCol.ValueType = GetType(Integer)
'comboCol.CellTemplate = New DataGridViewComboBoxCell
comboCol.Width = 150
.Columns.Add(comboCol)
```